# mod_rewrite rule for replacing string in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to replace a string from old URL:

```
http://www.homepage.com/projectname/public/ActionName.action
```

to

```
http://www.homepage.com/ActionName.action
```

or even

```
http://www.homepage.com/short
```

I got to this point (trying to it get shorten to `http://www.homepage.com/ActionName.action`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/projectname/public/(.*)$ http://www.homepage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I get a 404 error:

```
The requested resource (/projectnameActionName.action) is not available.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an `internal` redirection.

So if you want to be able to put URL's like this in the browser:

```
http://www.homepage.com/ActionName.action
```

But show a page like this:

```
http://www.homepage.com/projectname/public/ActionName.action
```

Then use this code in your.htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) http://www.homepage.com/projetname/public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Of course replace the domain name and folders to yours.